# Get mean of last N weekdays for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Assume my data is daily counts and has as its index a DateTimeIndex column. Is there a way to get the average of the past n weekdays? For instance, if the date is Sunday August 15th, I'd like to get mean of counts on (sunday august 8th, sunday august 1st, ...).

I started using pandas yesterday, so here's what I've brute forced.

```
# df is a dataframe with an DateTimeIndex
# brute force for count last n weekdays, wherelnwd = last n weekdays
def lnwd(n=1):
    lnwd, tmp = df.shift(7), df.shift(7) # count last weekday
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        tmp = tmp.shift(7)
        lnwd += tmp
    lnwd = lnwd/n  # average
    return lnwd
```

There has to be a one liner? Is there a way to use `apply()` (without passing a function that has a for loop? since `n` is variable) or some form of `groupby`? For instance, the way to find the mean of all data on each weekday is:

```
df.groupby(lambda x: x.dayofweek).mean() # mean of each MTWHFSS
```

Comment: There is a weekofyear method for DateTimeIndex. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for a rolling apply (rolling mean in this case)? See the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments. But then applied for each weekday seperately, this can be achieved by combining [`rolling_mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) with grouping on the weekday with `groupby`.

This should give somethin like (with a series `s`):

```
s.groupby(s.index.weekday).transform(lambda x: pd.rolling_mean(x, window=n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas Version 1.4.1 the solution provided by [joris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695211/10883115) seems outdated ("module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'"). The same could be achieved using

```
s.groupby(s.index.weekday).transform(lambda x: pd.Series.rolling(x, window=n).mean())
```